# Place the pagination in the middle

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pagination

I want to center the pagination but no matter what I do it doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klekv.png)
be like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n19V.png)

My css code :

```
`
.woocommerce-pagination {
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li {
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee !important;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 0 3px !important;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 32px !important;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0 14px !important;
    display: block;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers:hover, .woocommerce-pagination ul li span.current {
    color: #800080 !important;
    background: #f3f3f3 !important;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers:focus {
    color: #000000 !important;
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS rules instead (in short remove `float: right` from `li` element and add flexbox rules to `ul` element):

```
.woocommerce-pagination {
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li {
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee !important;
    margin: 5px 0 0 3px !important;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 32px !important;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0 14px !important;
    display: block;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers:hover, .woocommerce-pagination ul li span.current {
    color: #800080 !important;
    background: #f3f3f3 !important;
}
.woocommerce-pagination ul li .page-numbers:focus {
    color: #000000 !important;
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
```